# Automate regression based on the subset of two columns

Tags: r, windows

My data looks like this:

```
   country         y            x implicat
1        A 11.671385 -0.603552056        1
2        C  6.318847 -0.270256561        2
3        C 14.347812 -0.939150172        3
4        C  6.149730  0.530641352        4
5        B  2.746347  2.628195015        5
6        C 17.657281  0.205706484        1
7        A 11.619212 -0.184570364        2
8        B 16.559693  1.864309742        3
9        C 11.350414  0.005356281        4
10       A 15.929509  0.731629816        5
```

I want to automate my regression model with for loop based on the subset of two columns (country and implicat.

I have tried this:

```
for(i in unique(df$country) {
  for(j in unique(df$implicat)) {
    modelfits[[i]] <- lm(y ~ x, data = df %>% filter(country == i & implicat == j))
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea how I get this to work?
Thanks

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Where is that data stored?

Comment: Add a tag for the language you're using to help direct people to your question

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use for loop to automate? you can just use numpy arrays by extracting array with df.values and using np.stack() to stack the arrays. You can make use of the sklearn's linear regression to fit the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I am doing this in R.